# Sending messages to websocket stomp endpoints using @UserDestination

Tags: endpoint, stomp, spring-websocket

I followed the example https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends  AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/hello").withSockJS();
}

}
```

I am trying to add dynamic endpoints ex: /hello/user1, /hello/user2.

Would like to get some ideas on how to implement this?

So far, in the examples I am seeing, the endpoints are static.

I wish to segregate endpoints even selectively.

Answer (score 0):

I read about @UserDestination

and changed my @MessageMapping method to

```
@MessageMapping("/getfeeds")
public void subscribeToFeeds(Principal principal) throws Exception {
    String reply = "hello " + principal.getName();
    System.out.println("sending " + reply);
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName(), "/queue/getfeeds", reply);
}
```

In my javascript,
I am doing the following:

```
function connect() {
       var socket = new SockJS('/getfeeds');
        stompClient = Stomp.over(socket); 
        stompClient.connect('', '', function(frame1) {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected: ' + frame1);               
                // connect callback
                // subscribe to 
                stompClient.subscribe('/user/getfeeds', function(name) {
                    var msg = JSON.parse(name.body);
                    showGreeting(name);
                });
        });
    }
```

I also call stompClient.send("/app/getfeeds");

I am unclear on how to subscribe in client side using user destinations. Any comments or examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Ah. I found out my errors. These are the updates. 1) convertAndSendToUser(principal.getName, "/queue/messages", reply). 2) stompClient.subscribe('/user/queues/messages',...)